# Trouble with unresolved identifier self with NSTimer Swift

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have the code bellow and I am finding a error message. Note that the code in question is not in the viewcontroller class in Swift. The images code for moving is in the viewdidappear function.

```
var timer = NSTimer(timeInterval:3, target: self, selector:Selector("randomnumbers:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func randomnumbers(timer:NSTimer) {
    var rockNamesArray:[String] = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]    
    var rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))
}
```

Edit:

```
if rockNamesArray[rockpos] == "rock2"  {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
            self.mrock.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 167, y: 600), size: self.mrock.frame.size)
            },
            completion: { _ in
                self.mrock.frame = moriginalFrame
        })

    }
```

Comment: Which class is the code in then? Is the function in the same class?

Comment: The code you shared above is in the viewController? Or in viewDidAppear?

Comment: This is exactly what you asked before. Don't ask the same question twice, please. Edit your earlier question to be a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to declare your timer at your view controller class:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var rockNamesArray:[String] = []
var rockpos = 0
```

then at viewDidLoad you schedule the timer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "randomnumbers", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

//

```
func randomnumbers() {
   rockNamesArray = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]    
   rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(rockNamesArray.count)))
}
```

Comment: And is the randomnumbers function outside the viewDidLoad class? The self error is fixed but now it wont recognize rockNamesArray and rockpos in this.

   if rockNamesArray[rockpos] == "rock2"  {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
                self.mrock.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 167, y: 600), size: self.mrock.frame.size)
                },
                completion: { _ in
                    self.mrock.frame = moriginalFrame
            })
        
        }

Comment: yes otherwise it would be accessible only inside viewDidLoad method

Comment: Like above, Its telling me that rockNamesArray and rockpos are unresolved indetifiers. Any idea what could fix that?

Comment: rockNamesArray it is only accessible inside the method you need to declare it at your view controller class

Comment: Okay so it eliminated all the errors but now its giving me Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on this                  if rockNamesArray[rockpos] == "rock2"  {

Comment: make sure rockpos < rockNames.count

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by that. I edited in the code I am talking about in the main paragraph, can you show me what you mean?

Comment: try like this ==> rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(rockNamesArray.count)))